# Wolf and snake chimera

Tags: mythical-creatures

Is there any mythical creature that is a chimera between a wolf and a snake?

[Cerberus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus) could be considered one but he was definitely a dog, not a wolf.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific mythology?

Comment: "Wuk Ognezmij, the Fiery SnakeWolf - in slavic mythology the hero," https://cassiopaea.org/forum/index.php?topic=5310.0 ........... Ok..........

Comment: No specific mythology,  just curious.